# For which value $a$ can be chosen such $f(0)$ that the function is continuous function in 0?

Tags: analysis

I have a function:
$$f(x)=\frac{2e^{1/(2x)}-a}{\sqrt{a^2 - 1 + e^{1/x}}}$$
So I need to find parameter $a$ can be chosen such $f(0)$ that the function is continuos function in $0$?

Any help?

Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: "I have an aswer, but I do not know how to get to the answer." How did you get it then?

Comment: I have all answers in a book, but there is not any process of getting it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** I'm assuming you meant $e^{1/(2x)}$ and not $e^{\frac12x}$. The function $f_a(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$ because it has different limits as it approaches from the LHS and RHS. The goal is to make the two limits equal. We can reframe the one-sided limit from the right as $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(1/x)$ and likewise for the limit from the left.

The limit from the right becomes $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2e^{x/2}-a}{\sqrt{a^2-1+e^x}}=\lim\frac{(2e^{x/2}-a)/e^{x/2}}{(\sqrt{a^2-1+e^x})/e^{x/2}}=\lim\frac{2-\frac{a}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2-1}{e^x}+1}}$$

Find the terms that become negligible when $x\to\infty$ and then find a similar rearrangement for $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2e^{x/2}-a}{\sqrt{a^2-1+e^x}}$. Given that the limits at $-\infty$ and $\infty$ should be equal, you can find $a\approx−1.155$.

Comment: I actually meant $e^{1/2x}$ and $e^{1/x}$. So then is it the same?

Comment: @NikiSedlarevič That doesn't clarify it at all. I can't tell whether $1/2x$ is $\frac{1}{2x}$ or $\frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry for that. Thank you for hint